# Is there a closed form for $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{-x}\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there any closed formula for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{e^{-x}\sqrt{\cos x}\ dx}{\sqrt{\cos x} + \sqrt{\sin x}}?$

I know $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\sqrt{\cos x}\ dx}{\sqrt{\cos x} + \sqrt{\sin x}} = \dfrac{\pi}{4},$ replacing $x$ by $\frac{\pi}{2} - y$.

Comment: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-x}\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx=1-\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2e^{\arctan x^2}}$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, I don't think so that integral is enough to proceed. If you know how, then please let me know.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com) can handle this with: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}+\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x=0.452394$$ But I am not certain if the decimal is an algebraic function of some polynomial in $\pi$. I set this up in GP-Pari and got $1001$ digits for the decimal, but attempting to find an inverse symbolic constant failed, due to the sites being down for indefinite maintenance. Integral value: 0.452393721949631630101048738406004050830342774266050312052872034252790383557926597398320787147141929148773232260394691326515298869430720510690674

Comment: Using @Randall's result and a trigonometric inverse symbolic calculator, within an error of $1.5\times 10^{-9} $ $$\cos \left(\frac{27 \pi }{173}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{14 \pi }{99}\right)$$

Comment: I managed to achieve the following
$$I=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{\pi/2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cosh(\operatorname{arctan}{(x^2)})}{(x+1)^2}$$
If that $x^2$ were an $x$, we would have an antiderivative with hypergeometric functions, except it's not. I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Similarly, to @TheSimpliFire we expand $e^{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}$ to get:$$I=1-(-1)^\frac i2\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(1-\frac{2i}{x^2+i}\right)^\frac i2}{(x+1)^2}dx$$ Also, this old question would not have satisfied the modern MSE quality standards, but it is a “historic” question

Comment: Also, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-Nintegrate%5B%28-1%29%5E%28i%2F2%29+%28%28x-sqrt%28i%29%29%28x%2Bsqrt%28i%29%29%29%5E%28i%2F2%29+%28%28x-sqrt%28-i%29%29%28x%2Bsqrt%28-i%29%29%29%5E%28-i%2F2%29%2F%281+%2B+x%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D) is a form of the integral only in terms of a product of $(x-k)^r$. Maybe there is a hypergeometric function for $\int_0^\infty \prod\limits_n (x-a_n)^{r_n}dx$?

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-\theta}\sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}{\sqrt{\sin{\theta}}+\sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}d\theta=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-\theta}}{1+\sqrt{\tan{\theta}}}d\theta$$
With integration by parts with $u=(1+\sqrt{\tan\theta})^{-1}$ and $dv=e^{-\theta}$ we get
$$I=1-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-\theta} d(\sqrt{\tan{\theta}})}{(1+\sqrt{\tan\theta})^2}$$
Substitute $u=\sqrt{\tan\theta}$
$$I=1-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\arctan(u^2)}}{(1+u)^2}dx=1+\int_0^\infty e^{-\arctan{(u^2)}}d\left(\frac{1}{1+u}\right)$$
Then substitute $v=(1+u)^{-1}$
$$I=1-\int_0^1\exp\left(-\arctan\left((v^{-1}-1)^2\right)\right)dv$$
Use the logarithmic definition of the arctangent
$$I=1-\int_0^1\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+i(v^{-1}-1)^2}{1-i(v^{-1}-1)^2}\right)\right)dv$$$$=1-\int_0^1\left(\frac{1+i(v^{-1}-1)^2}{1-i(v^{-1}-1)^2}\right)^{i/2}dv$$$$=1-\int_0^1\left(\frac{(1+i)v^2-2iv+i}{(1-i)v^2+2iv-i}\right)^{i/2}dv$$$$=1-\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right)^{i/2}\int_0^1\left(\frac{v^2+(-1-i)v+(1+i)/2}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}\right)^{i/2}dv$$$$=1-i^{i/2}\int_0^1\left(1-\frac{(2v-1)i}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}\right)^{i/2}$$
Now we can use the following series I derived to continue. We can easily check it with negative integer inputs for k, and we can use the gamma function to expand it to the complex numbers
$$(1-x)^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(-k)}\frac{x^n}{n!}, k≠1,2,3,4,...$$
$$I=1-e^{-\pi/4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n-i/2)}{\Gamma(-i/2)}\frac{i^n}{n!}\int_0^1\left(\frac{2v-1}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}\right)^ndv$$
We can use special functions to solve this integral. I asked a question for this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588873/evaluate-int-01-left-frac2x-1x2-1-ix-frac121-i-rightndx-for?noredirect=1&lq=1). I'll add to this later

Let's handle this integral separately.
$$I_n=\int_0^1\left(\frac{2v-1}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}\right)^ndv$$
We want to substitute $w=\frac{2v-1}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}$, but we're going to need algebra first
$$w=\frac{2v-1}{v^2+(-1+i)v+(1-i)/2}$$
$$wv^2+(-1+i)wv+\frac{1-i}{2}w=2v-1$$
$$wv^2+((-1+i)w-2)v+(\frac{1-i}{2}w+1)=0$$
$$v=\frac{-((-1+i)w-2)+\sqrt{((-1+i)w-2)^2-4(w)((\frac{1-i}{2}w+1))}}{2(w)}$$
$$v=\frac{2+(1-i)w+\sqrt{-2w^2-4iw+4}}{2w}$$
$$v=\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1-i}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-2-4iw^{-1}+4w^{-2}}$$
$$dv=\left(-\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{iw^{-2}-2w^{-3}}{\sqrt{-2-4iw^{-1}+4w^{-2}}}\right)dw$$
$$dv=\left(-\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{iw^{-2}-2w^{-3}}{\sqrt{-2-4iw^{-1}+4w^{-2}}}\right)dw$$
$$dv=\left(-\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{iw^{-1}-2w^{-2}}{\sqrt{-2w^2-4iw+4}}\right)dw$$
Now that our substitution is prepared$$I_n=\int_{-1-i}^{-1+i}w^n\left(-\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{iw^{-1}-2w^{-2}}{\sqrt{-2w^2-4iw+4}}\right)dw$$
Let
$$J_n=\int_{-1-i}^{-1+i}\frac{w^n}{\sqrt{-2w^2-4iw+4}}dw$$
Then
$$I_n=\frac{(-1-i)^{n-1}-(1-i)^{n-1}}{n+1}+iJ_{n-1}-2J_{n-2}$$
and
$$I=1-e^{-\pi/4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n-i/2)}{\Gamma(-i/2)}\frac{i^n}{n!}\left(\frac{(-1-i)^{n-1}-(1-i)^{n-1}}{n+1}+iJ_{n-1}-2J_{n-2}\right)$$
I'll add more to this later. I already have a solution to $J_n$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an **experimental** result using a special case of [Lauricella D](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjzs5XMgOT7AhUCEmIAHT8aAIsQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLauricella_hypergeometric_series&usg=AOvVaw1EMmclcHEKYxmctGtupgX6) from the [**DLMF’s hyperelliptic $\text R$**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16) function which has a multiple series expansion, using the [Pochhammer symbol $(u)_v$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pochhammer+symbol), from

> [Is this Lauricella $\text F_\text D$ to hypergeometric R, from DLMF, conversion formula correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341436/is-this-lauricella-text-f-text-d-to-hypergeometric-r-from-dlmf-conversion):

$$\text B(-a,(-a)’)\text R_a(b_1,\dots,b_n;z_1,\dots z_n)=\int_0^\infty t^{(-a)’-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+z_j)^{-b_j}dt=\sum_{m_1\ge0}\cdots\sum_{m_n\ge0}\frac{(-a)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^nb_j\right)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{(b_j)_{m_j}(1-x_j)^{m_j}}{m_j!},(-a)’=a+\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$$

[Using](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-Nintegrate%5B%28-1%29%5E%28i%2F2%29+%28%28x-sqrt%28i%29%29%28x%2Bsqrt%28i%29%29%29%5E%28i%2F2%29+%28%28x-sqrt%28-i%29%29%28x%2Bsqrt%28-i%29%29%29%5E%28-i%2F2%29%2F%281+%2B+x%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D)

$$I=1-(-1)^\frac i2\int_0^\infty t^0(t-\sqrt i)^\frac i2(t+\sqrt i)^\frac i2(t-\sqrt{-i})^{-\frac i2}(t+\sqrt{-i})^{-\frac i2}(t+1)^{-2}dt$$

and $(-a)’=1=a-\frac i2-\frac i2+\frac i2+\frac i2+2\implies a=-1$

Therefore?:

$$I=1-i^i\text R_{-1}\left(-\frac i2,-\frac i2,\frac i2,\frac i2,2;-\sqrt i,\sqrt i,-\sqrt{-i},\sqrt {-i},1\right)$$

One problem is $x_5=1$ gives $(1-x_5)^{m_5}=0^{m_5}$ in the series expansion. Fortunately, the [function is homogenous](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16#E11):

$$1-(i^{-i})^{-1}\text R_{-1}\left(-\frac i2,-\frac i2,\frac i2,\frac i2,2;-\sqrt i,\sqrt i,-\sqrt{-i},\sqrt {-i},1\right) = 1-\text R_{-1}\left(-\frac i2,-\frac i2,\frac i2,\frac i2,2;i^{\frac 52-i},i^{\frac12-i},i^{\frac32-i},i^{-\frac12-i},i^{-i}\right) $$

Now for the possible series expansion

Comment: Also, see [Dirichlet average](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_average), which is new to me and includes the R function