# Is this Lauricella $\text F_\text D$ to hypergeometric R, from DLMF, conversion formula correct?

Tags: solution-verification, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals, reduction-formula

Here is another post about uncommon standard special functions in the form of [Elliptic Integrals](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19) which will be special cases of the [**Lauricella D function**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series). Most elliptic integrals can be put in terms of a double [hypergeometric functions like the Jacobi functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseJacobiND/26/01/) and others like the [Arithmetic Geometric Mean](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/ArithmeticGeometricMean/26/01/01/), [Elliptic Logarithm](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticLog/26/01/01/), and [Legendre Ellipctic functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_form) can all be put into closed form with a single or [double](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_function) [hypergeometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricSeries.html), but the [**Carlson Elliptic functions**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CarlsonRF.html) and [**Bulirsch’s Elliptic Integrals**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=Bulirsch%20elliptic%20integrals). Let’s start with some definitions which will allow integral and sum representations for the more complex elliptic integrals of a triple hypergeometric function with the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). The Lauricella D function is also in Wolfram functions

$$\text F_\text D^{(n)}(a,b_1,…,b_n,c;x_1,…,x_n)=\sum_{m_1\ge0}\cdots\sum_{m_n\ge0}\frac{(a)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}{(c)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{(b_j)_{m_j}x_j^{m_j}}{m_j!}=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n (1-x_j t)^{-b_j}dt$$

When the [Hyperelliptic hypergeometrc function from DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=hyperelliptic%20integrals) can give any elliptic integral as a special case:

$$\text R_a(b_1,..,b_n;z_1,…,z_n)=\frac 1{\text B(-a,(-a)’)}\int_0^\infty t^{(-a)’-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+z_j)^{-b_j}dt,(-a)’=a+\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$$

The problem here is that the integral bounds for the Lauricella function, so some substitutions help fix the bounds to put the Hyperelliptic function into Lauricella form:
$$\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}{\Gamma(c)}\text F^{(n)}_\text D(a,b_1,…,b_n,c;x_1,…,x_n)=\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n (1-x_j t)^{-b_j}dt \mathop=^{t\to\frac1t}-\int_\infty ^1t^{-a+1}(t-1)^{c-a-1}t^{-(c-a-1)}\prod_{j=1}^n (t-x_j )^{-b_j}t^{b_j}t^{-2}dt =\int_1^\infty t^{-c} (t-1)^{c-a+1}t^{b_1}\cdots t^{b_n}\prod_{j=1}^n (t-x_j)^{-b_j} dt =\int_1^\infty t^{-c+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j}(t-1)^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t-x_j)^{-b_j}\mathop=^{t\to t+1}_{t-1\to t} \int_0^\infty (t+1)^{-c+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j}t^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+1-x_j)^{-b_j} $$

Now assume the two hypergemoetric functions are equal:

$$\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}{\Gamma(c)}\text F^{(n)}_\text D(a,b_1,…,b_n,c;x_1,…,x_n) = \int_0^\infty (t+1)^{-c+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j}t^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+1-x_j)^{-b_j}= \text B(-a,(-a)’) \text R_a(b_1,..,b_n;z_1,…,z_n)=\int_0^\infty t^{(-a)’-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+z_j)^{-b_j}dt $$

Therefore the following is implied. Note that we had the same $a$ variable in both hypergeometric functions, so let’s represent one variable for the hyperelliptic function as $a=\alpha$:

$$t^{\alpha+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+z_j)^{-b_j} = (t+1)^{-c+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j}t^{c-a-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+1-x_j)^{-b_j} \implies z_j=1-x_j,c=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j=(-a)’-a,c-a-1= \alpha+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j-1 =\alpha +c-1\implies -a\to\alpha,a=-\alpha$$

and:

$$\implies \frac{\Gamma(-\alpha)\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j+\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j\right)}\text F^{(n)}_\text D\left(-\alpha,b_1,…,b_n, \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j;1-x_1,…,1-x_n \right)= \text B\left(-\alpha,\alpha+\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\right) \text R_\alpha(b_1,..,b_n;z_1,…,z_n)\implies \text R_\alpha(b_1,..,b_n;z_1,…,z_n) =  \frac{\Gamma(-\alpha)\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j+\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j\right) \text B\left(-\alpha,\alpha+\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j\right)} \text F^{(n)}_\text D\left(-\alpha,b_1,…,b_n, \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j;1-x_1,…,1-x_n \right) $$

The coefficients cancel. I have derived this simple looking formula before, and got the same result, but am not sure if it is correct:
$$\boxed{\text F^{(n)}_\text D\left(-a,b_1,…,b_n, \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j;1-x_1,…,1-x_n \right)=\text R_a(b_1,…,b_n;x_1,…,x_n) =\frac{\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}\prod\limits_{j=1}^n(1+tx_j)^{-b_j} dt}{\text B\left(-a,a+\sum\limits_{j=1}^nb_j\right)}= \sum_{m_1\ge0}\cdots\sum_{m_n\ge0}\frac{(-a)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^nb_j\right)_{\sum_{j=1}^n m_j}}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{(b_j)_{m_j}(1-x_j)^{m_j}}{m_j!} }$$

This is the basic expression of the conversion formula, but *is it correct*? We can now put any elliptic integral into a Lauricella hypergeometric form and have many new decomposition formula for the Lauricalla D function which is a standard function.

Maybe there will be some examples of special cases of the formula if it is correct. Specifically, the Carlson and Bulirsch’s elliptic functions, which also [appear](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BulirschEL/) on Wolfram, many of which can only be expressed as a special case of the Lauricella D function. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Better [R function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identity seems to be correct. Another derivation is presented below. By changing $t=(1-v)/v$ in the integral representation of the  multivariate hypergeometric function (here abreviated $\operatorname R_a$),
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname R_a(b_1,\ldots,b_n;z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\frac 1{\operatorname B(-a,(-a)')}\int_0^\infty t^{(-a)'-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(t+z_j)^{-b_j}\,dt
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{align}
 dt&=-\frac{1}{v^2}\\
 t+z_j&=\frac{1-v(1-z_j)}{v}
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
 \operatorname R_a&=\frac 1{\operatorname B(-a,(-a)')}\int_0^1
 (1-v)^{(-a)'-1}v^{-1-(-a)'+\sum_{j=1}^n b_j}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-v(1-z_j)\right)^{-b_j}\,dv\\
 &=\frac{\Gamma(-a+(-a)')}{\Gamma(-a)\Gamma((-a)')}\int_0^1
 v^{-1-a}(1-v)^{(-a)'-1}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-v(1-z_j)\right)^{-b_j}\,dv
\end{align}
By comparison with the Lauricella function
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname F_\text D^{(n)}(\alpha,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n,c;x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(c-\alpha)}\int_0^1t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{c-\alpha-1}\prod_{j=1}^n (1-x_j t)^{-\beta_j}\,dt
\end{equation}
with $\alpha=-a,\beta_j=b_j,c=-a+(-a)'=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$ and $x_j=1-z_j$, the proposed identity follows.