# Hilbert's 13th problem and the reduced septic $x^7+(x+p)(x+q)(x+r)=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, special-functions, closed-form

**I. Sextic**

The general sextic can be reduced to a two-parameter form,

$$Ax^6+Bx^2+x+1=0$$
$$y^6+y^2+ay+b=0$$

To transform $P(x)\to P(y)$ and vice versa is easy. They have solutions,

$$x = -\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (+1)^k \frac{(2j+6k)!}{j!k! (j + 5 k + 1)!}\; A^j B^k$$

and,

$$y_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac n6\right)!}{n!\,\Gamma\big(2-\frac{5n}6\big)}\,e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6(-p)^{1-\frac{5n}6}(-q)^\frac n6\,{_2 F_1}\Big(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\frac pq\Big)$$

where $p,q=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2.$ The first is by Robert Israel, while the second is by Tyma Gaidash in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728427/4781). Both are limited by different radii of convergence.

However, I was surprised by the second solution since the *hypergeometric function* ${_2F_1}$ is a **one**-variable function, whereas what should solve the general sextic is the *Kampé de Fériet function* which is **two**-variable. This has implications for deg-$7$ equations.

---

**II. Septic**

The general septic can be reduced to the 3-parameter,

$$u^7+Au^3+Bu^2+Cu+1=0$$

By a minor change of variables, this can be expressed as,

$$v^7+(v+p)(v+q)(v+r)=0$$

The [*Lauricella series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series) is a **three**-variable function and can perhaps solve the reduced septic. But *[Hilbert's 13th Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_thirteenth_problem)* asks if the septic's root can be expressed as the composition of a finite number of **two**-variable functions.

---

**III. Question**

Which brings me to my question. Can we solve the reduced septic in the same manner as Tyma did for the reduced sextic? Would the one-variable ${_2F_1}$ still do, or do we need something more general?

Comment: The summary for the sextic, septic, and octic can be found in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450112/12905).

Comment: Why do you say that ${_2F_1}$ is one-variable?

Comment: @Anixx The three-variable _Lauricella series_ generalizes the two-variable _Appell series_ $\text{F}_1\big(a_1,\, b_1, b_2;\, c;\, x_1, x_2\big)$ which in turn generalizes the one-variable hypergeometric $_2F_1\big(a,\,b;\,c;\,x_1\big).$ One can classify this plethora of functions by the parameter $x_i$, and the "mother" Lauricella series can be further generalized to more than three $x_i$. Kindly google it for more details.

Comment: But the expression ${_2 F_1}\Big(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\frac pq\Big)$ also depends on $n$

Comment: @Anixx Of course. But if you look at the definition of the hypergeometric $_2F_1$, $$_2F_1(a,b;c;x_1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{x_1^n}{n!}$$ one way to generalize such functions is to increase the number of $x_i$. And a better question is "why does the _literature_ say $_2F_1$ is one-variable"? Or the "why is the Appell two-variable?" These are their labels before you and I were born.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reduced Septic:**
$\def\F{\operatorname F}$

$\def\FD{\operatorname F_\text D}$

We apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728427/4781):

$$z^7+(z+p)(z+q)(z+r)=0\iff z=e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i }7(z+p)^\frac17 (z+q)^\frac17 (z+r)^\frac17\implies z_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i (n+1)}7}{(n+1)!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(z+p)^\frac{n+1}7 (z+q)^\frac{n+1}7 (z+r)^\frac{n+1}7\right|_0$$

Now use a strategy like in [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904) with the [multinomial product rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#More_than_two_factors) and [Pochhammer symbol $(m)_n$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/16/02/):

$$\left.\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(z+p)^\frac{n+1}7 (z+q)^\frac{n+1}7 (z+r)^\frac{n+1}7\right|_0=\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3=n}\binom n{n_1,n_2,n_3}(pqr)^\frac{n+1}7\left(-\frac1p\right)^{n_1} \left(-\frac1q\right)^{n_2} \left(-\frac1r\right)^{n_3}\left(-\frac{n+1}7\right)_{n_1} \left(-\frac{n+1}7\right)_{n_2} \left(-\frac{n+1}7\right)_{n_3}$$

where the [generalized Chu-Vandermonde identity $(1)$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1243.pdf) and [Lauricella $\F_\text D ^{(n)}$ function transformation $(10)$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1243.pdf) in the linked paper appear. We have $3$ indices $n_j$, so we use $\F^{(2)}_\text D$ which reduces to the **two**-variable [Appell $\F_1$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppellF1.html),

$$F_1\big(a;b_1,b_2;c;\beta_1,\beta_2 \big)$$

With [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html), we get:

$$\bbox[2.5px,border:5px groove blue]{\begin{align}
&z^7+(z+p)(z+q)(z+r)=0\implies \\
&z_k =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}7\frac{(pq)^\frac n7}{r^{\frac{6n}7-1}n!}\left(\frac n7\right)^{(n-1)}\F_1\left(1-n;-\frac n7,-\frac n7;2-\frac{6n}7;\frac rp,\frac rq\right)\\
&\text{for}\,k=0,\dots, 6.\end{align}}$$

Plugging in arbitrary parameters $(p,q,r)$ [gives all roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bsum%5Bexp%28%282*%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%7D%2B1%29+pi+i+n%2F7%29%2Fn%21+%28%282%2B5+i%29+%28-8+-+0.3+i%29%29%5E%28n%2F7%29+4%5E%281-6+n%2F7%29+factorialpower%28n%2F7%2Cn-1%29+AppellF1%281+-+n%2C+-n%2F7%2C+-n%2F7%2C+2+-+%286+n%29%2F7%2C+4%2F%282%2B5+i%29%2C4%2F%28-8+-+0.3+i%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%5D) which [match](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5E7%2B%28z%2B2%2B5+i%29%28z-8-0.3+i%29%28z%2B4+%29%3D0) the actual ones. Alternatively, using the more familiar ***gamma function*** $\Gamma(n)$ and by permuting $(p,r)$,

$$z_k =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}7 \, \frac{(qr)^\frac n7}{p^{\frac{6n}7-1}} \, \frac{\;\left(\frac n7\right)!}{n!\,\Gamma\big(2-\frac{6n}7\big)}\, \F_1\left(1-n;-\frac n7,-\frac n7;2-\frac{6n}7;\frac pq,\frac pr\right)$$

makes it ***very*** similar to hypergeometric ${_2F_1}$ solution to the reduced *sextic* in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728427/4781),

$$z_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6 \frac{(-q)^\frac n6}{(-p)^{\frac{5n}6-1}} \frac{\left(\frac n6\right)!}{n!\,\Gamma\big(2-\frac{5n}6\big)}\,{_2 F_1}\left(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\frac pq\right)\qquad$$

This same method works on the reduced octic, but for degrees $m\geq9$, we cannot factor part of the polynomial in radicals. For example $z^9+a_5z^5+\dots +a_1=z^9+(z-r_1)\dots(z-r_5)=0$ has $r_j$ that cannot be put in terms of radicals in general. This means the generalized Chu-Vandermonde identity cannot be used to find a single sum of a Lauricella function solution for its roots $z_k$, like in this answer, unless we allow “non-radical” $r_j$.

**Reduced Octic:**

A sum of the [Lauricella $\FD^{(3)}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series) function appears after continuing the pattern:

$$\bbox[2.5px,border:5px groove blue]{\begin{align}&z^8+(z+p)(z+q)(z+r)(z+s)=0\implies \\ &z_k =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}8\frac{(qrs)^\frac n8\left(\frac n8\right)!}{p^{\frac{7n}8-1}\left(1-\frac{7n}8\right)!n!}\FD^{(3)}\left(1-n;-\frac n8,-\frac n8,-\frac n8;2-\frac{7n}8;\frac pq,\frac pr,\frac ps\right)\\
&\text{for}\,k=0,\dots, 7.\end{align}}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fd0f77a4-a85b-4ac5-968d-13989984ff18) using $\FD^{(3)}$’s triple sum definition.

Comment: Beautiful! This seems to be the _complete_ solution to the reduced septic since the Appell function has an analytic continuation that makes it valid for general $\beta_1, \beta_2$. (See this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series).) And I've given an alternative formula using gamma functions which makes it look **very** similar to sextic solution you found. Excellent!

Comment: I can already see the trend. For $n=6$, we need Gausss ${_2F_1}$ with one variable $\frac pq$, for $n=7$ is Appell with two variables $\frac pq, \frac pr$, and for $n=8$ is presumably Lauricella with three variables $\frac pq, \frac pr, \frac ps$. Since you mentioned the octic, care to complete the family and give another answer below, for the octic? (One can give two answers.) I assume it will look very similar to $n=6,7.$

Comment: Yes, I saw that sentence. Surprisingly, there is a way the Bring-Jerrard method can eliminate 4 terms at once, but it starts with general equations of degree $n\geq10$. However,  the case $n=9$ is special because Hilbert, using a geometric method involving 27 straight lines on a surface and intersecting one of those lines with a hypersurface, reduced it to, $$x^9+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e =0$$ However, the actual procedure is probably **very** complicated. See Section 4 of [Sutherland's 2021 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09247). So your method can still apply at $n=9$, but no more after that.

Comment: I re-read Sutherland's paper. To get Hilbert's nonic, it seems one may have to solve a deg-5 or deg-6 (much less than deg = 4! = 24), so it may not be in radicals after all.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII In that case, an alternative method to partly factoring the equation, like in this answer,  would be using a more general version of [Glasser’s derivation for the quintic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Other_characterizations), but the problem is that we get expressions like a sum with indices $j,k$ of $\Gamma(j+4k+2)$, as seen in Robert Israel’s solution. The [Gauss multiplication theorem](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/16/02/0004/) for $\Gamma(n z+b)$ seemingly cannot make a sum over $\Gamma(j+k+a), \Gamma(j+a)$, and $\Gamma(k+a)$.

Comment: I'm content the procedure can be extended all the way to the octic. While the Lauricella function can be generalized to any $n$ variables, there doesn't seem to be much interest for 4 variables and above. Like I pointed out, I can't even find in the literature an explicit example of a Kampé de Fériet function that solves a single sextic.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Not exactly, an idea of how to convert a sum, say with indices $n,m$, with summand in terms of $\Gamma(a m+b n+c),a,b\in\Bbb N$ into the same sum, but with a summand in terms of $\Gamma(n+d), \Gamma(m+d)$, and/or $\Gamma(n+m+d)$ with $c,d\in\Bbb R$. Thanks for the help and sorry for the long conversation.

Comment: No, unfortunately. Let's see the octic solution and compare how similar it is to the others.

Comment: Note to all: the Lauricella function can be [reduced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341436/is-this-lauricella-text-f-text-d-to-hypergeometric-r-from-dlmf-conversion) to the DLMF’s hyperelliptic R function. It [relates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_average#Notable_Dirichlet_averages) to a “Dirichlet average”.

Comment: Now that the family (sextic, septic, octic) is complete, I have asked a question in MO summarizing the results. Kindly see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450112/12905).